# Is a piecewise linear function always a sum of concave and convex functions?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polytopes, piecewise-continuity

If I take a piecewise linear function (piecewise affine) is it true that I can always write it as a sum of concave and convex functions?

My understanding of this page

https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/cv1/t

suggests that any linear function is both convex and concave, so for a piecewise linear function is it always possible to 'separate' the convex and concave parts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me assume that you are talking about a real-valued function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. A characterization of which such functions may be written as $f=g-h$ with $g$ and $h$ convex (so $-h$ concave) is known. The result is the following (see [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cqyHkkCxVtcC&pg=PA22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

> Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists $g$ and $h$ convex such that $f = g-h$ if and only if the derivative of $f$ is in the class $BV[a,b]$ of functions of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) on $[a,b]$.

Here, "derivative" is in the sense that there exists a function $r \in BV[a,b]$ such that, for all $x \in [a,b]$,
$$ 
f(x)-f(a) = \int_a^x r
$$

Hence, the answer to your question is both *yes and no*. If you take an $f$ which is piecewise affine but has discontinuities, then you will not be able to find such a decomposition. Conversely, if it is continuous, then its derivative will be piecewise constant, so of bounded variation, so the above result applies.

Comment: Discontinuous functions on a finite interval $[a,b]$ are in BV if they are bounded and if there are only finitely many discontinuities. I think that's pretty much the case the OP had in mind.

Comment: Sure. But here the characterization requires that the **derivative** is BV, not the function itself. Having a BV derivative implies continuity.

Comment: Ah, yes. And I now also realize that the decomposition of a piecewise but discontinuous function would likely also be discontinuous, and discontinuous functions are neither convex nor concave.